# How can I modify values in a map using range based for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop, dictionary

I have a range based for loop to iterate over elements in `foobar` as follows:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::map<int, int> foobar({{1,1}, {2,2}, {3,3}});

  for(auto p : foobar) 
  {
    ++p.second;
    std::cout << "{" << p.first << ", " << p.second << "} ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  for(auto q : foobar) 
  {
    std::cout << "{" << q.first << ", " << q.second << "} ";
  } 
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

This code produces the following output:

```
{1, 2} {2, 3} {3, 4}
{1, 1} {2, 2} {3, 3}
```

The first line is modified and printed inside a for loop and the second line supposedly prints the same modified values.  Why don't the outputs match?  Are changes to `std::map` only effective in the scope of the loop?  Is there a way I can not only access but modify these values?

A [running version of this code](http://cpp.sh/6rxx) can be found on cpp.sh.

**EDIT:** The example given here was modified to match the accepted answer for clarity.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can turn `auto` into `auto&` if you want to mutate/modify the container, for instance:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::map<int, int> foobar({{1,1}, {2,2}, {3,3}});
  for(auto& p : foobar) {
    ++p.second;
    std::cout << '{' << p.first << ", " << p.second << "} ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

compiles ands outputs

```
{1, 2} {2, 3} {3, 4}
```

[live example](http://ideone.com/CXcH5b)

Answer (score 12):

Plain `auto` is by value (you get a copy). Use `auto&`.

Answer (score 12):

Note that since **C++17**, you can use *structured bindngs*:

```
for (auto & [key, value] : foobar)
  std::cout << "{" << key << ", " << ++value << "} ";
```

I like this mechanism since `key` and `value` is much more readable for maps than something as `p.first` and `p.second`.

Comment: I don't believe that this works. If I do `static_assert(std::is_reference_v<decltype(value)>);` it fails.

Comment: @DavidW You may want to read this rule about `decltype` when used with structured bindings: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type.simple#4.1.

Comment: Thank you - I didn't know that. I'm thoroughly confused about that rule, but I now believe it works.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `auto` keyword sends a copy of each value into the loop. If you want to mutate the original value in the map you need to use `auto&`.

Comment: _"when using `for(auto val : myMap)` operations done to `val.second` are read-only."_ That is not true.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​You _are_ "allowed" to modify those values. It's just that in your original code you were modifying _some other values_ instead (copies of the original values). Nothing's "read-only". Did you see the other answers?