# Modification via iterator not reflecting

Tags: c++, list, c++11, vector, iterator

I have a list of Slide objects. Each Slide object has a vector of slide elements, the slide element vector is of another class,say ItemProperties that has members

int Resize
int Rotate
int Move

and the functions to modify these values

```
void ResizeItem(int resize_val);
void RotateItem(int rotate_val);
void MoveItem(int move_val);
```

I am iterating the list of object like this
"Iterating Part"

```
                        auto slidelist_ptr=VDECK.getSlideList(); /*returns list<Slide> by reference */
                        auto slidelist_itr=slidelist_ptr.begin(); /*returns iterator to beginning of Slide list*/
                        auto slidelemnts_itr=slidelist_itr->getSlideElemnt().begin(); /*returns iterator to beginning of slide list elements*/
                      
                            in1=_getch();
                            if(in1!=KEY_ARROW_1)
                            {
                                **VDECK.selectedSlideOperations((*slidelist_itr),in1-48);**
                                throw std::runtime_error("Operation success\n");
                            }
                        
                        ++slidelist_itr;
                        slidelemnts_itr=slidelist_itr->getSlideElemnt().begin();
```

In the function selectedSlideOperations , I am passing the particular slide object and taking it as reference in function like this

```
 void Deck::selectedSlideOperations(Slide &obj,int choice)
 {
switch(choice)
{

case 5:
    ChangeSlideItemProperties(obj);
    break;
```

}
}

In ChangeSlideItemProperties , I am again taking the object as reference

```
   void Deck::ChangeSlideItemProperties(Slide &obj)
   {
         for(auto p=obj.getSlideElemnt().begin();p!=obj.getSlideElemnt().end();p++)
                    {
                        std::cout<<"before \n";
                        p->PrintItemProperties();
                        p->RotateItem(input);
                        std::cout<<"\nafter \n";
                        p->PrintItemProperties();
                    }
   }
```

Inside this I am iterating the Slide object's slide elements(which is a vector) and trying to modify the value of member "Rotate" for all the elements in vector.
After modification when I print "before" and "after" the members ,the value reflects properly for member Rotate.
However after modification ,when I exit this menu and print the slide elements using iteration as shown in "Iterating part" , the values are 0's for all the members.

I am fairly new to C++ , please bear with me.... I am not sure what am I missing here.

**Edit**: Sorry I changed the slide elements to list instead of vector , so I have lists only and no vectors

Edit 2: Adding minimal reproducible example

```
using namespace std;
class Itemprop
{
    int Rotate;
public:
    Itemprop():Rotate{0}{}
    void Set_Rotate(int val)
    {
        Rotate = val;
    }
    int Get_Rotate()const
    {
        return Rotate;
    }
};

class Dummy
{
    public:
        Dummy();
        list<Itemprop>& getList(void)
        {
            return v;
        }
        virtual ~Dummy();

    protected:

    private:
        list<Itemprop> v;
};
int main()
{
    Dummy dobj;
    Itemprop iobj;
    iobj.Set_Rotate(1);
    dobj.getList().emplace_back(iobj);
    Itemprop iobj2;
    iobj2.Set_Rotate(2);
    dobj.getList().emplace_back(iobj2);
    for(auto p:dobj.getList())
    {
        cout<<"before\n";
        cout<<p.Get_Rotate()<<endl;
        p.Set_Rotate(3);
        cout<<"after\n";
        cout<<p.Get_Rotate()<<endl;

    }
    for(auto p:dobj.getList())
    {

        cout<<p.Get_Rotate()<<"<--new\n";
    }
```

Output is

```
before
1
after
3
before
2
after
3
1<--new
2<--new
```

Comment: auto& is your friend

Comment: just a guess, is `getSlideElemnt()` returning a copy? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Can you post [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) pls. You would not need to describe in the details what is going on if you simplified your problem first and post a relevant code that we can compile and run.

Comment: @idclev463035818 getSlideElemnt returns list by reference
std::list<ItemProperties>& Slide::getSlideElemnt(void)
{
    //std::cout<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__<<"\n";
    return slide_elements;
}

Comment: there was an answer that mentioned a potential problem. I don't understand why it was deleted. Anyhow, please post a [mcve]

Comment: @pptaszni , basically the relevant part of code is ChangeItemProperties where the actual modification is taking place... an mvce for this would be to pass an object by reference of a class that has a list as member and try to modify the list elements by iterating like I have done , does this sound ok?

Comment: @Klaus , could you please help me understand where and why to use auto & , I am still learning , Thanks

Comment: @idclev463035818 , oh ok , could you think of something I should look at that might give me a hint? ,Thanks
Let me try to create that , it is going to take a while

Comment: something you should look at that will give you a hint: a debugger

Comment: I gave an answer... but the guys here have downvoted. So it feels it was wrong. Sorry.

Comment: @idclev463035818 , I tried to create a dummy class and tried to do the same thing , please see if this is good for a minimal repr. example ,Thanks in advance

Comment: ok guys I got it working now
but please explain to me if possible
I just changed auto p , to auto &p like @Klaus suggested  , the modification is reflecting now

Comment: My answer had an explation to that, cames with some hints and also has a full code example... but ok, if the downvoters needs to kill the answer... no problem!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I modify values in a map using range based for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31795106/how-can-i-modify-values-in-a-map-using-range-based-for-loop)

Answer (score 1):

Because your range loop that uses `auto` keyword is taking the elements of your list (the list itself is taken by reference) by copy.

Quick fix is to take the elements by reference as well, e.g.:

```
for(auto& p:dobj.getList())
```

Or you can use the `std::list` iterators, like in the previous code you posted:

```
    for(auto it = dobj.getList().begin(); it != dobj.getList().end(); it++)
    {
        cout<<"before\n";
        cout<<it->Get_Rotate()<<endl;
        it->Set_Rotate(3);
        cout<<"after\n";
        cout<<it->Get_Rotate()<<endl;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @pptaszni for the detailed answer